# Weblogic 12 SSL setup with Demo Trust Keystore

Tags: java, ssl, https, weblogic

I have following setup

TestDomain1 running on port 7001 (SSL Listen port not enabled)

- wls console -> AdminServer -> Keystore tab

  ```
    Keystores: Demo Identity and Demo Trust
    Demo Identity Keystore: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\TestDomain\security\DemoIdentity.jks
    Demo Trust Keystore:
  ```

  C:\PROGRA~1\ORACLE\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks
- wls console -> AdminServer -> SSL tab

  ```
    Identity and Trust Locations: Keystore
    Certificate Location: from Demo Identity Keystore
    Trusted Certificate Authorities: from Demo Trust Keystore and Java Standard Trust Keystore
  ```

TestDomain2(SSL Enabled) running on port 9001 and SSL listen port is 7002.

```
 Exactly same setup as above domain (so both domain were created with
 default setup and I have not made any changes except enabling SSL
 listen port in this domain)
```

I have a webservice running on TestDomain1 and this webservice calls an HTTPS URL on TestDomain2. I am getting following error on TestDomain1

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

What does this error mean. Based on the above setup truststore path is already given in TestDomain1. I am not trying 2 way SSL. I just want to be able to invoke and HTTPS URL.

Following is my code to access the HTTPS URL

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

```
    ProtocolSocketFactory factory = new SSLProtocolSocketFactory();
    Protocol https = new Protocol("https", factory, 7002);
    client.getHostConfiguration().setHost("localhost", 7002, https);

    PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://localhost:7002/somecontext/someresource");
    post.setParameter("sapCreateRequest", request.getSapRequestPayload());
    try {
        client.executeMethod(post);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(post.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            logger.info(line);
        }
        // print response to stdout
        System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsStream());
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Error while communicating with SSL resource: {}", ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // be sure the connection is released back to the connection 
        // manager
        post.releaseConnection();
    }
```

Comment: Have you imported the SSL cert from TestDomain2?  The error is saying it hasn't been told how to trust TestDomain2.  You may also have to add the keystore to your JAVA_OPTIONS as `-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=${path_to_truststore} -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${path_to_truststore}`

Comment: Since both domain created with same setup, which use same trust store(C:\PROGRA~1\ORACLE\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks) I am assuming that both domains will have same SSL cert in DemoTrust.jks? and an HTTPS call to TestDomain2 will return the certificate that is already there in TestDomain1 truststore. I have not created a separate certificate.

Comment: I will try to create a new certificate and import it.